# Problema bcrypt en python

Tags: python, bcryptjs

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo

```
@app.route('/login/<nameUsuario>',methods=['POST'])
def login(nameUsuario):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contrasenaRequest = request.json['contrasena'].encode('utf-8')
        
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO = %s""", (nameUsuario,))
        user = cur.fetchone()  
        cur.close()
        contrasenaUser = user[2].encode('utf-8')
        if len(user) > 0:
            if bcrypt.hashpw(contrasenaRequest,contrasenaUser)  ==  contrasenaUser:

                status_code = 202
                usuario = {
                    "id": user[0][0],
                    "usuario": user[0][1],
                    "fotourl": user[0][3]
                }
                return jsonify(usuario),status_code
```

**Pero me tira el siguiente error** | invalid salt
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la variable contrasenaUser, como la contrasenaRequest, llegan los datos.. el problema esta,creo,en la linea: if bcrypt.hashpw(contrasenaRequest,contrasenaUser)  ==  contrasenaUser:

No se porque me tira este error, osea probe hacerlo de la siguiente forma y tampoco funciona.

```
if (bcrypt.checkpw(contrasenaRequest,contrasenaUser)):
```

Answer (score 2):

La función `bcrypt.hashpw(passwd, salt)` tiene el siguiente [esquema](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/blob/d22ece077755fa375a65739965da20323c500ea7/src/bcrypt/__init__.py#L76): recibe como argumento una contraseña y un *salt* que debe tener un [formato concreto](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/blob/d22ece077755fa375a65739965da20323c500ea7/src/bcrypt/__init__.py#L55).

`hashpw(password: bytes, salt: bytes) -> bytes`

El fallo lo tienes al estar pasando un salt que no respeta las normas. Además, tienes que llamar a la función con el **mismo** *salt* con el que generaste el *hash* que almacenaste en la base de datos o de lo contrario, nunca coincidirían.

Esto lo puedes hacer de dos formas: bien lo haces almacenando el *salt* en la base de datos o... usando la función que te ofrece bcrypt para comprobar si una contraseña es equivalente a un *hash* generado con anterioridad (que previamente almacenaste en la base de datos): `bcrypt.checkpw(passwd, hashed)`

```py
if len(user) > 0:
            if bcrypt.checkpw(contrasenaRequest,contrasenaUser):

                status_code = 202
```

Comment: si de hecho lo estaba hacendo con checkpw pero me seguia dando mal, el problema que lo estaba haciendo con la contraseña en la base de datos que fue generada sin el hash, gracias